# How to declare global variable in codeigniter?

Tags: php

This is my path.$t is my variable which holds the path.one time change want to reflect everywhere ??

```
$t="/var/www/upload/videos_comm/";
```

Comment: Use a constant - http://php.net/define, globals are bad mojo.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the file in `/application/config` called `constants.php`. You can use that file to declare your global variable.

Or you can use [define](https://www.php.net/define) as Pankucins suggested like this:

```
<?php
define("CONSTANT", "Hello world.");
echo CONSTANT; // outputs "Hello world."
echo Constant; // outputs "Constant" and issues a notice.

define("GREETING", "Hello you.", true);
echo GREETING; // outputs "Hello you."
echo Greeting; // outputs "Hello you."

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best place to declare `global variable` in `codeigniter` is the `constants.php` file in the directory `/application/config`

You can define your global variable as follows

```
/**
 * Custom definitions
 */
define('first_custom_variable', 'thisisit');
$yourglobalvariable = 'thisisimyglobalvariable';
```